# Not able to retrieve data from a MySQL database into html using flask

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I'm making a flask website app, I have connected a MySQL database but I'm not able to get the data into my HTML file. The data is supposed to show up in a side navigation but nothing is showing up(its blank). The purpose of this is to avoid hard coding text so that I can easily update pages that require the same text. Any better way to achieve the same result would also be appreciated. Any help is appreciated, Thank you

**These are my imports and setup**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'my_password_changed'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'swebsite'


mysql = MySQL(app)
```

**This is the function that is trying to retrieve the data**

```
@app.route('/menu/internships')
def internships():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM professional")
    fetchdata = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    datas = {}
    # for j in fetchdata:
    datas['first'] = f"{fetchdata[0][1]}"
    datas['second'] = f"{fetchdata[1][1]}"
    datas['third'] = f"{fetchdata[2][1]}"
    datas['fourth'] = f"{fetchdata[3][1]}"

    print(datas)
    return render_template('internships.html', data = datas)
```

**This is where I'm trying to use the data**

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    {% for j in data %}

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('professional')}}">{{j['first']}}</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('internships')}}">{{j['second']}}</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('projects')}}">{{j['third']}}</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('respon')}}">{{j['fourth']}}</a>

    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Could you update your post with the value of `datas` before the `render_template` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're fetching data correctly, `datas` is a dictionary.
So, the for loop in the html is unnecessary.

Could you give this a shot?

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('professional')}}">{{data['first']}}</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('internships')}}">{{data['second']}}</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('projects')}}">{{data['third']}}</a>
    <a href="{{url_for('respon')}}">{{data['fourth']}}</a>
</div>
```